# How do I extend my menu bar past the margin?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have a menu bar on top that I want to extend infinitely horizontally.  On top of that, I would also like the same properties to apply to the HTML slider  as well if possible.  Additionally if done correctly the menu bar should horizontally extend forever and the container underneath it should as well.  Last but not least the 2 gray boxes I have.  I want their gray background to expand outwards horizontally as well but the separator in between the 2 columns should still exist.

This is what I have:
[image]
This is what I want:
[image]

```css
@font-face { font-family: UbuntuG; src: url('ubuntu-fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf'); } 
*{ box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
body { background-color: #2d2d2d; }
h1 {
    color: #1d1d1d; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30;
}
h2 {
    color: #1d1d1d; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 18;
}
p {
    color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16;
}
td  {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 48px;
    min-width:48px;
}
a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
   color: #1d1d1d;
   font-family: UbuntuG;
   font-size: 16;
     
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #1d1d1d;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #33d6ff; color: white;
}
.active {
    background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;
}


.selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
/*Top full width container*/
.FullWidthContainer{ width:100%}
/*Content Container With max-width:1200px for example*/
.MainContainer{max-width:1200px; width:100%; margin: 0px auto; }
/* content containre divided in left-75% and right-25%}*/
.left{ width:70%; padding:2%; float:left;}
.spacer{ width:2%; padding:2%; float:center}
.right{ width:28%; padding:2%; float:right}
.right img{ width:100%}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <meta content="??">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <style>
        table, th, td { border: 5px solid white; border-spacing: 0; color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; }
        h1 { color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="FullWidthContainer" style=""><ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
  <!-- Start cssSlider.com -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/style.css">
  <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.css"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <div class="csslider1 autoplay ">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_play1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor" checked="">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <ul>
   <li class="cs_skeleton"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></li>
   <li class="num0 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
   <li class="num1 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
   <li class="num2 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download_2.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
  <!-- </ul><div class="cs_engine"><a href="http://cssslider.com">http://cssslider.com</a> by cssSlider.com v2.1</div> -->
  <div class="cs_description">
   <label class="num0"></label>
   <label class="num1"></label>
   <label class="num2"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_play_pause">
   <label class="cs_play" for="cs_play1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num0" for="cs_pause1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num1" for="cs_pause1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num2" for="cs_pause1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   </div>
  <div class="cs_arrowprev">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_arrownext">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_bullets">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download_2.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End cssSlider.com -->

 <br><br>
    <div class="FullWidthContainer">
  <div class="MainContainer">
   <span style="background-color: gray;" class="left"><center>
    <iframe height="400px" width="550px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src=https://hellodj.airtime.pro/embed/weekly-program></iframe>
   </center></span>
   <div style="background-color: gray;" class="right">
    <iframe id="embed_player" frameborder="0" width="280" height="216" src="https://hellodj.airtime.pro/embed/player?stream=auto"></iframe>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your menu looks fine (it stretches to fill page width). Can you post a screenshot of what the intended look should be?

Comment: I added the images to the question good sir

Answer (score 0):

Take out the default padding and margin. Add this to the top of your CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Apocolyptic glad to hear. Make sure to mark the answer as correct for future members with a similar issue.